# Incompatibility between Hibernate 6 and Apache Spark latest version

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, apache-spark, hibernate-6.x

We are trying to use Apache spark in our existing application. Spark is using `Antlr4` version `4.9`.
While Hibernate is using `Antlr4` version `4.10`.

Antlr has made changes between 4.9 version and 4.10 version which is causing below issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4).
```

We are using below dependencies in our application which is running with **Spring Boot 3.2.3** and **Java 17**. Below are the maven dependencies we are using.

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can use [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) to relocate the hibernate version?